# Do embassies give you your documents back?

Tags: visas, embassies, consulates

You show them birth certificate, financial docs, etc. Do they give them back?

I don't remember the last time I visited an embassy/consulate so I don't remember.

Answer (score 19):

Each embassy or consulate may have its own procedures for exactly what will and won't be returned, so we can't give you a firm answer without knowing where your documents are going. But in my experience (mostly with German and Russian authorities) "common sense" can be applied quite consistently:

Documents which can typically be reproduced easily (for example, a bank statement or a letter confirming employment) will not be returned.

Documents which are essentially "single-use" (for example, the tourist invitation letter required when visiting Russia) will not be returned.

If they want to see documents which are not single-use and are less trivial to have reproduced (birth certificates would probably fit here), either:

- these documents will be returned, or
- you will be asked to provide a copy (pay attention, they may need a notarised/apostilled copy) rather than the original.

Comment: My birth certificate is just a computer printout stamped by a civil servant…

Comment: @gerrit Don't you mean "typewriter" or are you very young?

Comment: @gerrit That "stamp" is likely to actually be embossed, and is what the poster was referring to as a notarized copy. A notary, more or less, is a recognized third party that has been granted the authority to say "Yes, this is a legitimate official document." They emboss things rather than stamp them, because you can't photocopy an embossment.

Comment: Sometimes consulates will make their own copy on the spot too.

Comment: @AndreKR: I can't imagine that gerrit meant "typewriter printout", seeing as that's not really a thing. Computers have been around for a while now, and anyway, birth certificates aren't necessarily only issued *at* birth. The last time I needed my birth certificate, my father went to the Ministry of the Interior for me and had them print it out. (And that was more than twenty years ago!)

Comment: Even with important documents, you should be careful - different governments approach them differently. For instance, in Ontario (Canada), your birth certificate is considered unique - the government will not issue you a second one, and an official copy is not the same as the original. In Poland, meanwhile, copies of your birth certificate are a dime a dozen, and a government office will cheerfully make as many as you like. As a consequence, Polish procedures involving birth certificates will typically retain the provided copy, even if it's foreign and you can't easily obtain another one.

Comment: @AndreKR I was born 1985.  I suspect that either birth certificates were digital by then or they were digitised at some later date.

Answer (score 7):

It may depend on the embassy.

But usually, if they do not ask for original document explicitly, no they will not return documents to you. Check on visa documentation (for your specific country/embassy/type of visa), they should state if they return originals. In any case, assume also a "no": things are lost of it will take too much time, so never give embassy an important document you cannot easily get again. Especially if you need several visas (be sure you have a copy of all documents, you may find late that you need a transfer visa, etc).

Often a copy is enough, else a notarized copy should be enough.

Sometime you need original document, but often are just documents you get just for this visa (health insurance letter that tell you are covered during the travel, invitation letters, etc.).